# Using python command if a condition is true in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I wanted to convert the below code into list comprehension.

```
for i in list:
    if i>b:
        i=5
    else:
        i=0
```

I tried to use `[i if i>b 5 else 0 for i in a]` but it resulted in a syntax error. I have also tried `[i for i in a if i>b 5 else 0]` but that too resulted in a syntax error.

Any solutions?

Comment: `[5 if i > b else 0 for i in a]`

Comment: I don't understand what that loop does. Why are you modifying the loop iteration variable?

Comment: @JohnKugelman , I was trying to make a program which list all combination of number till a specific number, and if the digit of the iteration variable is less than the digit of the given number, i want to add 0 to the iteration variable. for example if the given number is 23, and i= 4, i want i to be 004. I hope i have clear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
[i if i>b 5 else 0 for i in a]
```

Is close, you just want to give `5` not `i` like so:

```
[5 if i>b else 0 for i in a]
```

Test code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = 3
output = [5 if i>b else 0 for i in a]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

This works because the item before the `if` is given when the statement evaluates to `True` and the value after the `else` is given otherwise. So:

```
output = NumberIfTrue if LogicStatement else NumberIfFalse
```

is equivalent to :

```
if LogicStatement:
    output = NumberIfTrue
else:
    output = NumberIfFalse
```

In your case:

```
LogicStatement = i>b
NumberIfTrue = 5
NumberIfFalse = 0
```

Thus you need (as shown above):

```
5 if i>b else 0
```

Then you want to apply this to every item in a list which adds:

```
for i in a
```

like so:

```
5 if i>b else 0 for i in a
```

This is now a generator, since you want a list, you have to surround the generator with `[]` brackets so that it "generates" the list with the values you want. So just:

```
[5 if i>b else 0 for i in a]
```

Then to get the final solution we just assign the result to `output` so it can be used again:

```
output = [5 if i>b else 0 for i in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

In your version

```
  [i if i>b 5 else 0 for i in list]
```

The syntax error is right after the i>b.
You have the "true value" there, it is in the wrong place.
Riffing on your original code

```
for i in list:
    if i>b: #condition
        i=5 #true action
    else:
        i=0 #false action
```

The real answer is

```
[5 if i > b else 0 for i in list]
```

the pseudo code version

```
[<true action> if <condition> else <false action> for i in list]
```